# Magnitude of 3D vector functions in relation to its derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If the magnitude of a 3D vector function is always 1, then is the derivative of that function always perpendicular to the original function?

Comment: how do you take the derivative of the 3D vector function?

Comment: What is a magnitude of a function? Some kind of norm?

Comment: Sorry here is a clarification. If |r(t)| = 1 for all t, then r'(t) is orthogonal to r(t) for all t. Im wondering if this is always true.

Comment: $||\textbf{r}(t)||=1$ means the end point of $\textbf{r}(t)$ is always touching the unit sphere centred on the origin. The derivative is going to be tangent to the unit sphere, so $\textbf{r}(t)$ and $\textbf{r}'(t)$ are perpendicular.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's true. If $r(t)=(x(t), y(t), z(t))^T$, then $\|r\|=\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$, and if $\|r\|=1$ you have (by squaring)

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1.$$

Differentiating both sides by $t$ using the product or chain rule yields

$$2xx' + 2yy' + 2zz' = 0$$

which can be written using the dot product

$$2\ r \cdot r' = 0,$$

so $r$ and $r'$ are orthogonal to each other.

Answer (score 0):

If $\| \mathbf{r}(t) \| = 1$, then we have

$$
  2\mathbf{r}(t) \cdot \frac{\mathbf{r}(t)}{dt}
= \frac{d}{dt} \Big(  \mathbf{r}(t) \cdot  \mathbf{r}(t) \Big)
= \frac{d}{dt}\left( \| \mathbf{r}(t) \|^2 \right)
= \frac{d}{dt}(1)
= 0
$$
So $\mathbf{r}(t) \cdot \mathbf{r}'(t) = 0$, which means that $\mathbf{r}(t$ and $\mathbf{r}'(t)$ are perpendicular.